# Android TabHost Example

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I did and run example. But i take error.

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tabmenu/com.example.tabmenu.MainActivity: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: you must specify a way to create the tab indicator.
```

#### mainActivity.java

```java
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class MainActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        TabSpec tab1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First Tab");
        TabSpec tab2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");
        TabSpec tab3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third Tab");

        tab1.setIndicator("Tab1");
        tab1.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab1Activity.class));

        tab1.setIndicator("Tab2");
        tab1.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab2Activity.class));

        tab1.setIndicator("Tab3");
        tab1.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab3Activity.class));

        tabHost.addTab(tab1);
        tabHost.addTab(tab2);
        tabHost.addTab(tab3);
    }
}
```

#### androidManifest.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tabmenu"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity 
            android:name="com.example.tabmenu.Tab1Activity"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tabmenu.Tab2Activity"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tabmenu.Tab3Activity"/>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.tabmenu.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try to change this segment:

```
tab1.setIndicator("Tab1");
tab1.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab1Activity.class));

tab1.setIndicator("Tab2");
tab1.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab2Activity.class));

tab1.setIndicator("Tab3");
tab1.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab3Activity.class));
```

with the below one .... like this:

```
tab1.setIndicator("Tab1");
tab1.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab1Activity.class));

--> tab2.setIndicator("Tab2");
--> tab2.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab2Activity.class));

--> tab3.setIndicator("Tab3");
--> tab3.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab3Activity.class));
```

The error is because your are not using tab2 or tab3 and using tab1 repeatedly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your manifest like this (Bunu denermisin manifestinde)

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.tabmenu.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
    </activity>

     <activity
        android:name="com.example.tabmenu.Tab1Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.tabmenu.Tab2Activity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name="com.example.tabmenu.Tab2Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.restaurant.Tab2Activity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.tabmenu.Tab3Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.tabmenu.Tab3Activity" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Sorunun ilk kısmını hallettim. Her sınıf için ayrı activity etiketi açmam gerekiyormuş. Şuan başka bir hata alıyorum.

Error: You must specify a way to create the tab indicator.

Comment: @c.mert plz write in english :)

Comment: ok than i will write english. Where did you take error in your main page.

Comment: @Ziprox09 he solve problem in manifest part but he is taking new problem now which is Error: You must specify a way to create the tab indicator.

Comment: @Ziprox09 sorry :) Now i found my problem :) i should write;

    tab1.setIndicator("Tab1");
    tab1.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab1Activity.class));

    tab2.setIndicator("Tab2");
    tab2.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab2Activity.class));

    tab3.setIndicator("Tab3");
    tab3.setContent(new Intent(this,Tab3Activity.class));

But i used tab1 for everyone so it didnt work :) but now it is working. Thanks all.

Comment: @c.mert now is it ok in emulator ?

Comment: it is ok in galaxy note 2. I dont use emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...it may help

```
public class Test extends TabActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;
    Intent intent;

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab1Activity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("First").setIndicator("First")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab2Activity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second").setIndicator("Second")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab3Activity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third").setIndicator("Third")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


}
```

Corresponding xml Page......

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:id="@android:id/tabhost">

        <LinearLayout 
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
                android:orientation="vertical" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">

                <TabWidget 
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                </TabWidget>

                <FrameLayout 
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                     android:layout_width="fill_parent">
                </FrameLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the given statement

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
```

to

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
```